# Converting TimeStamp Series into minutes Series data || Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I'm looking for method to convert a timestamp series data into minutes of the days data.

For example:
05:30:00 is 330 minutes
13:10:00 is 790 minutes
Also if day changes and timestamp is of next day, it continues this series
Like 1440 + next day minutes.

```
0   2021-02-01 06:20:40
1   2021-02-01 05:25:45
2   2021-02-01 06:35:40
3   2021-02-01 05:32:45
4   2021-02-01 05:37:30
5   2021-02-01 05:39:22
6   2021-02-01 06:51:40
7   2021-02-01 06:10:04
8   2021-02-01 06:28:57
9   2021-02-01 05:49:23
```

Here's dummy data.
I don't wanna loop each element and calculate it because there are multiple timestamps columns in my DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, make sure the dtype of the Series (df column in question) is datetime
- now subtract the date of your choice, e.g. first entry of Series (which you can obtain by [`normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html))
- take the `total_seconds` of resulting [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) Series and divide by 60 to get minutes (you could also floor-divide `//` if you don't want the fractional minutes)

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["2021-02-01 06:00:00", 
                              "2021-02-01 09:00:00", 
                              "2021-02-02 01:00:00"]))

minutes = (s-s.iloc[0].normalize()).dt.total_seconds()/60

minutes
0     360.0
1     540.0
2    1500.0 # next day -> 1440 + time of current day
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Works like a charm..!
Could you explain (s-s.iloc[0].normalize()) this part ..?

Comment: @Brainiac: `s.iloc[0]` takes the first element of the Series. You can change that to whatever you need. `.normalize()` is a Timestamp method that floors the time to 00:00, i.e. giving you only the date. I subtract that from the initial Series to get just the time (as timedelta) without the date.